# React dropdown - dynamic key value pairs with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, list, generics, mapping

I have a custom doropdown that takes a key value pair

```
export interface People {
  id: number | string;
  name: string;
}
```

These are passed in as an object

```
  <Dropdown
      dataList={people}
       value={values.person}
                    
    />
```

These are mapped over and output in a list

```
<ListItem id={person.id}>{ person.name }</ListItem>
```

I have another list I want to map over

```
[
 {
   placeId: 1,
   placeName: 'Paris',
   country: 'France'

},
{
   placeId: 2,
   placeName: 'Barcelona',
   country: 'Spain',
}

]
```

Now the only way I can think of doing it is mapping over and sanitise the data, returning an array of key-value pairs to match the component (id, name). Then transforming back.

Is there a way to make the dropdown more generic to take the first 2 properties as ones to map over and ignore the rest?

Comment: What is your question? Can you clarify which array you're trying to achieve what with?

Comment: I want to use both arrays in the one compoent. Without mapping the data.

Comment: What do you mean both arrays there is only one array shown above